# How do I run `n` python coroutines concurrently?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have created an `async` python coroutine with `async def`, and I would like to run it over every element on a list.

However, the coroutine launches a separate process, and my computer has limited resources, so I would like to only run `n` of these coroutines at the same time.  When one finishes, I would like another one to be started.

I'm still learning `asyncio` and I'm lost how to do this within this framework.

I know I can run `n` jobs concurrently by using something like this:

```
commands = asyncio.gather(*[run_command(f) for f in islice(my_large_list,n)])
# Run the commands
results = loop.run_until_complete(commands)
```

However, I don't know how to replace each job as it is completed.

Comment: you want to use `multiporcessing` with `asyncio`? if that is the case: i tried that with treads; not exactly the same but might get you an idea how to get there,

Comment: I don't really want to use multiprocessing with asyncio.  I'm trying to call out to an external process...  Another way of putting this: I want concurrency, not parallelism.

Comment: sorry, i am confused... asyncio will run on a single thread; no need to worry about limited resources. otoh: starting processes *will* result in parallelism (not concurrency). so which is it? could you post a toy example of your coroutine then? (i'd be interested in how you `await` a process you start).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I'm running the python program single threaded, but it is creating child processes using `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec`.  This question, however, is about how to only run `n` async coroutines at once, in some kind of queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [`asyncio.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore):

```
import asyncio

import random

s = asyncio.Semaphore(5)


async def my_coroutine(i):
    async with s:
        print("start", i)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(1, 3))
        print("end", i)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [my_coroutine(i + 1) for i in range(50)]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
loop.close()
```

**Update**: [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) would probably solve your problem in a much easier way than asycnio, since executors has a very simple max_workers argument:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

import random


def my_routine(i):
    print("start", i)
    # Here you can use subprocess.* for anything, instead we will sleep:
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 3))
    print("end", i)
    return "i={}".format(i)


with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    jobs = {executor.submit(my_routine, i + 1) for i in range(50)}
    for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(jobs):
        print(fut.result())

print('done')
```

Comment: I think for IO tasks, ThreadPoolExecutor is preferred to ProcessPoolExecutor